# Default video app keeps resetting from MPV

Tags: applications, video, vlc

### The Problem

I use the [`mpv`](https://mpv.io) video player to play all videos on my mac, though I also have `VLC` installed. The problem is that after a while my default video application changes to VLC (and/or Quicktime, depending on the file type/extension) without any apparent reason and trying to change it back gives an error.

---

### What it looks like

The whole process is a *bit weird* and this doesn't happen always, but when it does, it looks like this every single time:

1. I double click on a video file, and it opens up in `mpv` (since it is set as the default video application for a lot of formats i.e. `mkv`, `mp4`, etc.)
2. The video ends (or I close it) and open another video. It opens in `VLC`. At this point, the video file icons still identify `mpv` [as the default application and are listed under it](https://jmp.sh/0NvgsJ8) in Finder, until I change directories.
3. I open `Get Info / Inspector` to set the default app (It correctly [shows the VLC video icon](https://jmp.sh/fMTqZCL) since that is the default at this point).
4. Here's the *Weird Thing 1*: **`mpv` is greyed out in the application list** (It's not usually).

   [image: MPV greyed out]
5. But still selecting `mpv` and clicking `Add` gives this error:

   > **You can't change the item "My Video.mkv" to always open in the selected application.**
   >
   > The item is either locked or damaged, or in a folder you don't have permission to modify (error code -9499).

   [image: Error on changing default video app]

6. Here's the *Weird Thing 2*: Since I have no choice but to close inspector at this point, **mpv becomes the default app automatically** after closing it. But when opening a video, the OS thinks that I am opening MPV for the first time and shows this dialog:

   > **You are opening the application "mpv" for the first time. Are you sure you want to open this application?**
   >
   > The application is in a folder named "HEAD-xxxxxxx". To see the application in the Finder without opening it, click Show Application.

   [image: Running mpv the first time]
7. The thing to note here, is that if I don't even attempt to change the application, `VLC` (or QuickTime) would remain the default. So even though I was unable to "successfully" set `mpv` as the default, it becomes the default as soon as I close the file `Inspector / Get Info` dialog.
8. `mpv` remains the default video app for an indeterminate period of time until it happens again

---

### Reproducing It

While this has been happening for months now, I've been unable to consistently reproduce the issue or pinpoint the cause. *It just happens™️*, sometimes twice in one day, sometimes after weeks.

---

### What I've tried

- Tried upgrading MPV
- Completely removed and tried installing from different sources

  - Homebrew binary with bundle (using this currently)
  - Homebrew cask
  - Compiled release from the official website/github

Comment: the SIP in Mojave is keeping it sandboxed. When you try to play a video are they from your HD or from the web ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 From the hard drive.